# Responsive row with overflow-x scroll and text aligned to the left, center and right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I developed a row with a scroll overflow x in reduced screens.

Is there a way to align the text to the left, center and right on the same line?
I intend to achieve the same, but with the text aligned in several positions.

[Demo in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxweje?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Code**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-md-center flex-nowrap myrow" style="margin-top: 148px;">
  <span style="margin-right:15px">LEFT</span>
  <span style="margin-right:15px">CENTER</span>
  <span style="margin-right:15px">RIGHT</span>
</div>
```

```
.myrow {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: As Azametzin told you, you can add "justify-content-between" class on the parent. And you can also remove the margin on spans.

Comment: Good, I forgot to mention that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `justify-content-between` class to it.
And then, you can remove the margins as well.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-md-center flex-nowrap myrow" style="margin-top: 148px;">
  <span>LEFT</span>
  <span>CENTER</span>
  <span>RIGHT</span>
</div>
```

This is a class of Bootstrap that applies `justify-content: space-between` for flex elements.